# find in array of objects with nested array of objects with multiple property name and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, find

I have Array of objects like this

```
[{
    property1: 'test',
    property2: 'test',
    filter: [{
        fil1: 1,
        fil2: 2,
        fil3: 3
      },
      {
        fil1: 56,
        fil2: 3,
        fil3: 34
      },
      {
        fil1: 23,
        fil2: 88,
        fil3: 6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    property1: 'test2',
    property2: 'test2',
    filter: [{
        fil1: 44,
        fil2: 5,
        fil3: 99
      },
      {
        fil1: 333,
        fil2: 7,
        fil3: 888
      },
      {
        fil1: 10,
        fil2: 5,
        fil3: 688
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

as you can see i have two objects. each object have nested array with objects. i want to get main object if i search for some properties inside nested array of objects.

for example fil1: 56, fil2:3 , i need to get first main object in first match. but there is trick. property names inside nested objects are dynamic and i need to search sometimes by one property or 5 property. i have search object like this

```
{
  fil2: 2,
  fil3: 3
}
```

entering this searching object will return first main object in array.

Comment: Use `Object.entries()` to convert an object to an array of `[key, value]` nested arrays. And use `Array.prototype.every()` to test if all the keys and values in such an array can be matched in a given object.

Comment: And use `Array.prototype.some()` to search the `filter:` arrays for a match with that.

Comment: here is exact data. first variable contains many objects with nested property ''localizedAspects". second variable is what im searchin inside 'localizedAspects' playcode.io/1047211

Comment: Please show your attempted solution. I pointed you to all the functions you need.

Comment: i will try your methods now. before i just tried nested find method and when i go in correct array i have dynamic size object to match objects in array.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.find((el) => el.filter.some((el_n) => !Object.entries(search).some(([key, value]) => el_n[key] != value)));
```

where `data` is searchable array of objects and `search` is search object. This will return the first matching object from `data`.

This will work for any number of keys inside `filter` array element or in search object.

eg:

```
{
    fil1: 5,
    fil2: 5,
    fil3: 686,
    fil4: 686,
    search_by_this_key: 34,
    ...
}
```

Filtering arrays client side on a large data set can impact performance, in that case you might want to look into a backend solution.

Comment: here is exact data. first variable contains many objects with nested property ''localizedAspects".

second variable is what im searchin inside 'localizedAspects'

https://playcode.io/1047211